# How to get FileSystemStats like totalNumberFiles, totalFileSize, maxFileSize etc on SparkSQL?

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, hiveql, hadoop2

In hive, to get the FileSystemStats like total number of files we run the query

```
Show table extended like '<db>.<table>' partition(<partition>)
```

I tried running

```
show table extended from <db> like '<table>' partition(<partition>);
```

On SparkSQL, but this query does not give the total number of files, max file size etc...

Comment: spark version ?

Comment: spark sql version 2+, we use 2.0/2.1/2.2/2.3/2.4/